# Android SDK minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion

Tags: android

I set my android app with below SDK settings. If some using android device with high version > 17. Will my App be run without problem on that device? Thanks.

android:minSdkVersion="11"
android:targetSdkVersion="16"

Comment: why are you setting android:targetSdkVersion = "16" ??? just curious

Comment: Yes. But you should always target the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, it will work(on api level greater than `17`) without any major issue, there may be user experience related problems on latest versions(say 5.0 or 5.1).

**But it is `recommended` to use latest SDK level as target sdk.**